# Get referrers for a post

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer, views

In the last week, I've seen [a sudden influx of upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40846742/timeline) to my post [RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility#40846742) . Apparently, someone has shared it on some popular resource or something.

Can I somehow see the `Referer`'s of the visitors or voters in some form to get an idea of what is going on?

Comment: Nope, that data is not available for users and I even think mods don't have access. You would need SE staff and then I'm unsure if they have it in the db. Might need logfile inspection.

Comment: It might be the following question originally posted on Github that refers to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571703/numpy-dtype-size-chaged-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-expected-96-got-88

Comment: According to google it is GitHub where it first got noticed. See https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22RuntimeWarning:+numpy.dtype+size+changed,+may+indicate+binary+incompatibility%22&num=30&newwindow=1&tbs=qdr:w,sbd:1&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV5MWe_sXcAhWjOn0KHSHiC-AQpwUIIQ&biw=1308&bih=558

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-referrers-for-a-specific-question

Answer (score 2):

According to *[Can we have a way to see referrers for a specific question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-referrers-for-a-specific-question#comment845117_99058)* and *https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics*, the [Site Analytics privilege](http:///help/privileges/site-analytics) (awarded at 25k as of this writing) gives access to Google Analytics data for the site from the last 30 days (though what "access" means here is anyone's guess).

As per *[Google Analytics – Traffic Source of Specific Page](https://pagecrafter.com/google-analytics-traffic-source-of-specific-page/)*, the stock Google Analytics UI allows to get a per-page referrer information.

Comment: I have access to the site analytics panel.  It's not granular enough to inspect at an individual question level.

Comment: the `linked:` operand Google offers used to be _much_ more useful than it currently is in sussing this out, and new referrers would often show up within 48 hours. I'm not sure if this changed due to crawl frequency, policy, the phase of the moon or all of the above, but I'll check into it. There are some webmaster-y reasons why we never implemented a feature that would look much like a pingback/trackback feature, but I don't know how relevant those would be these days. Will look into it.

Comment: @Makoto the link in the 2nd paragraph says it's not on the dashboard but rather can be browsed to from it. So, you're saying that the "analytics panel" is not a flavor/adaptation of the stock GA UI, and there's nothing in it similar to what the link describes?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev:  That's right.  This analytics panel is nothing like anything related to Google Analytics; it seems to be an aggregate on bulk of all questions and answer-related traffic.  It's useful to see what's going on at a macro level.  Not valuable at a micro level.

Comment: To add to Makotos comment - "access to site analytics" page has very few values: total pages/visits per day, top 20 referrals sources, and top 20 search engines sources (not queries, just a list of search engines and number of entries). All numbers are aggregated for the whole site, there is no drill-down at all to any level.