# Increase close and reopen vote weight for tag badge holders

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

<sub>(This is one of the suggestions that were listed in [What does our long term community need? What does our long term community need to feel valued?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t/373501#373501).)</sub>

Subj (I believe it's clear without further clarification).

The intent is to make reviewers more efficient -- hopefully efficient enough to crunch through the incoming close votes.<sup>1</sup>

The cost is somewhat weakening the concensus in review decisions. That's why I've specifically picked tag badges as the criterion (rather than e.g. [general reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/give-high-rep-users-extra-weight-on-close-votes)) -- users with contribution to the specific tag are more likely to know what they are doing for the specific question than users with unspecified contribution (I would love to see some numbers though).

[Increase close and reopen vote weight for bronze and silver tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240150/increase-close-and-reopen-vote-weight-for-bronze-and-silver-tag-badge-holders) outlines other potential drawbacks that might have been the reason for rejecting that earlier proposal. None of them seem to apply to SO at the present moment:

- *It's very easy to earn a tag badge, a holder would have insufficient contribution to be granted higher vote weight*

  - This is the complete opposite of my experience. I currently have almost 20k reputation and only 3 tag badges (two bronze and one silver), one of which is [due to a random streak of luck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371700/get-referers-for-a-post). For me, it has been *extremely* hard to get any number of upvotes on answers. Without hard figures, I cannot vouch for how typical my situation is, but [existing statistic confirms a steady decline in average answer score over time.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/363226/answers-per-month-and-average-answer-score-per-month)
- *[would make] the system too complicated*

  - For SO specifically (as opposed to all of SE) and at the present moment (as opposed to 2014), the review queue problem is sufficiently bad to justify the added complexity
- *[would confuse] users as to why the question was closed by fewer users than normal*

  - This is not an issue. First, how many users have closed/reopened the question is none of the OP's business really -- all that concerns them is that the community's quality assurance system has failed/passed their question. Second, if the badges are shown near the users' names (as they already are for the dupe-hammer), there will be no confusion about the reason, either.

---

Additional details to flesh out are:

- Specific weights (duh!).

  - I'm okay with 2, 3 and 4 (but other suggestions are welcome). The idea is that a gold badger's vote is *almost* binding but not quite -- they'll be able to single-handedly close a question reported by someone, but not on their own.
  - <sub>(These don't even need to be whole numbers -- fractions could be represented as [fixed-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).)</sub>
- How multiple tag badges shall synergise.

  - I considered some things like adjusting the additional weights from badges by the tags' correlation coefficient (the more the tags correlate in questions, the less weight the additional badge adds) but this seems too complicated for the task.
  - The highest-level badge prevailing seems good enough.

---

Previous relevant discussions:

- [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212)
- [Bronze and/or silver tag badge holders should earn additional privileges, like weighted close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317490/bronze-and-or-silver-tag-badge-holders-should-earn-additional-privileges-like-w)
- [Give high-rep users extra weight on close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/give-high-rep-users-extra-weight-on-close-votes)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is also the reason why I'm suggeting this here rather than at meta.SE -- the close vote queue problem is SO-specific, I dunno how relevant it is on other sites across the network</sub>

Comment: Related: [Shog9's suggestion to allow badge holders to delete a question and require an edit for undeletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts/374490#374490)

Comment: Related on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240150/increase-close-and-reopen-vote-weight-for-bronze-and-silver-tag-badge-holders

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I wrote that the close votes queue problem is much worse at SO specifically, so this idea is likely to have much more support here than on the network at large.

Comment: @Stijn Considering Shog's big picture perspective, my position is to stick to the YAGNI principle: when making concrete suggestions/decisions, concentrate on what you _know, right now._ Apply changes that will definitely make a difference, _when_ you get to know that they will make a difference. Walking local maximums, if you like.

Comment: Just repeating previously ignored feature requests is not that useful, it will just be ignored again.  You first have to figure out exactly *why* it was ignored.  And adjust your proposal accordingly.  Hard to do when the SO employees refuse to respond.  But you no doubt can get some theories from meta users.

Comment: @HansPassant: summing up your comment to "feature requests will just be ignored again"

Comment: @HansPassant I assumed that poor reception was the reason for rejecting the request at MSE and didn't look further.

Comment: @JJJ I trust the [2nd law of dialectics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectical_materialism#Engels%27s_dialectics). Even if it's ultimately ignored on its own, a well-received FR will definitely contribute to its goal down the line. References elsewhere around the Net, some other solutions (maybe even competing ones), maybe even make a "social media incident" if you like (whatever that is).

Comment: related: [Dupe-hammer reopen question based on the closer's least popular gold tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323331/4279)

Answer (score -2):

I'll admit I'm biased, but I'd be more comfortable if new tag-specific privileges like this were handed out on the basis of the user's score in the tag rather than upon tag badges.

A gold tag badge has two requirements: 1000 upvotes on answers in the tag, and 200 answers in the tag. I can see the merit of using this as a condition for handing out the dupehammer, since both of those factors are important qualifications there: we want dupehammer users to have demonstrated competence in the tag, and we *also* want them to specifically have interacted with *lots of Stack Overflow questions in the tag*, because that will help them remember and recognise duplicates.

It seems to me, though, that the number-of-answers requirement is irrelevant to a person's ability to judge other closure reasons. Why should somebody with five 200-score answers in a tag be given radically less power to judge if a question is unclear than somebody with 200 5-score answers in the tag? If anything, I'd trust the former person more.

But maybe this is just sour grapes. Full disclosure: I'm a user who's passed the score threshold for two gold badges, but hasn't passed the number-of-answers threshold for even a silver badge in any tag yet; at this rate, I won't get any gold badges until the middle of next decade. Perhaps I'm just coming up with a rationalisation for why this threshold is bad because it wouldn't give *me* powers that I'd like to have. I'll let the community judge and vote accordingly.

[image: Screenshot showing the "Select your next badge" modal, showing a choice between pursing a silver Python badge (for which I currently have 1211/400 score and 70/80 answers) or a silver JavaScript badge (for which I currently have 1284/400 score and 46/80 answers).]

(This answer was posted at the OP's suggestion after he and I argued about this point extensively in the comments.)

Comment: While I agree you probably have a point, deciding on badges is much easier to understand (and perhaps even to implement). I am afraid perfect could become enemy of good here. Perhaps you would like to change the criteria for the badges instead?

Comment: There are enough examples of people with only 1 answer that has 1000+ upvotes, that doesn't necessarily prove they have incredibly knowledge of the topic. Often those are just very old, popular questions with an easy, straight-forward answer (I'm not saying those are bad answers by the way).

Comment: @AlexanderDerck There are also examples of people with gold badges who have contributed nothing to their tag but an endless stream of answers to crap debugging questions, and have never produced anything of lasting value. Neither "gold badge" nor ">1000 tag score" is a perfect predictor of a high-quality contributor, but which criterion has the worse false positive rate? The answer is non-obvious (and subjective, of course).

Comment: @MarkAmery I think they both have high enough of an FP rate that neither along is a good indicator. So, why not use both?

Comment: I don't like the idea of giving people special close powers because of a high score and low number of answers. I mean, if you have one 10000 score answer, you answered one question really well, but that doesn't mean you have a thorough knowledge of the tag. It just means you were able to help one person with one question.